# how to convert window.scroll() for mobile touch?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I want to be able to detect the scrollTop() value during a scroll on mobile. Using window.scroll() works but only when the scroll has finished, not during.

How can I constantly detect the scroll y value in mobile? and run functions if its at a certain point etc?

Thanks!

EDIT:

code im using now is:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", refreshPage, false);

function refreshPage(){
        scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollY <= 740){
            $('.pullDownLabel').text('Release to refresh...');
        }else if(scrollY > 740){
            $('.pullDownLabel').text('Pull down to refresh...');
        }
}
```

however this still only executes when you finish touching the screen, I need a way to loop this function constantly during a scroll. any ideas?